# Finding Specific dates in Date range

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

In here i need to get Sundays in given date range.When i give the date range,
SelectedStartDate is 7/1/2013  & SelectedEndDate is 7/31/2013 then this code returns Sundays are  7/2,7/9,7/16,7/23,7/30 But my expect dates are 7/7,7/14,7/21,7/28

```
 static IEnumerable<DateTime> SundaysBetween(DateTime SelectedStartDate, DateTime SelectedEndDate)
    {

        DateTime current = SelectedStartDate;

        if (DayOfWeek.Sunday == current.DayOfWeek)
        {

            yield return current;
        }
        while (current < SelectedEndDate)
        {

            yield return current.AddDays(1); 

            current = current.AddDays(7);
        }

        if (current == SelectedEndDate)
        {

            yield return current;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question?  What problem are you having?

Comment: @Amy Wrong dates returning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
static IEnumerable<DateTime> SundaysBetween(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    DateTime currentDate = startDate;

    while(currentDate <= endDate)
    {
        if (currentDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
            yield return currentDate;

        currentDate = currentDate.AddDays(1);
    }         
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    public IEnumerable<DateTime> SundaysBetween(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        while (start.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
            start = start.AddDays(1);

        while (start <= end)
        {
            yield return start;
            start = start.AddDays(7);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished pretty easily using `AddDays` without over complexing the issue too much.  Here's a short snippet I wrote to demonstrate:

```
// Setup    
DateTime startDate = DateTime.Parse("7/1/2013");
DateTime endDate = DateTime.Parse("7/31/2013");

// Execute
while (startDate < endDate)
{
    if (startDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
    {
        yield return startDate;
    }
    startDate = startDate.AddDays(1);
}
```